# Selecting fields from mongodb query

Tags: node.js, mongodb

```
var users = db.users.find({});
```

User has: _id, name, age.

I am trying to print the users so i can see their data, but when i `console.log(users)` it prints:

```
Query {
  _mongooseOptions: {},
  _transforms: [],
  _hooks: Kareem { _pres: Map {}, _posts: Map {} },
  _executionCount: 0,
  mongooseCollection: ...
...
```

Is is possible any way so i can console something like this: `console.log(users[0]).['name']` so i can see the name of the first element in the array of users?
I tried to `JSON.parse(users)` but it raises an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use await or fn like

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await

```
db.users.find({},function (err, data) {
        console.log(err,data)
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
db.users.find({},{name:1},function (err, usersdata) {
    usersdata.forEach(function(user){
        console.log(user.name)
    });
});
```